# What's this round token depicting a knight?

Tags: identify-this-game, small-world

I found this token while cleaning up.

[image]

The size and shape looks like it's from Small World, but I looked through my game and expansions and didn't see anything missing or any descriptions of a token matching it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a token from [*Small World: Realms*](https://www.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/realms/). You can see it listed on page three of [the Realms rules (PDF)](https://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_realms_rules.pdf) in the top left. They're listed as: “1 Rusted Throne & 7 Miscellaneous Tokens to use in Scenarios of your own creation”. I'm not sure whether you ought to have multiple or just the one Knight token in Realms.